# Express & Node.js Exception: 500 TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a Node.js project using Express and got this exception when using a customized routes.

> 500 TypeError: fn is not a function
>   at callbacks (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
>   at param (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
>   at pass (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
>   at Router._dispatch (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:5)
>   at Object.Router.middleware [as handle] (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
>   at next (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
>   at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:35:5)
>   at next (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
>   at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:88:61)
>   at next (/WallaceBot/WallaceBot/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)

And I declare the routes in app.js by

```
var webhook = require('./routes/webhook.js');
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/webhook', webhook);
```

And in my webhook.js,

```
/*
 * GET Webhook.
 */

exports.webhook = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Webhook' })
};
```

However, I use another way to declare the route in app.js, like

```
app.get('/webhook', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Webhook' })
});
```

I don't get that exception.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative solution to the other answer you may change your webhook.js file to look like this:

```
/*
 * GET Webhook.
 */

exports = module.exports = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Webhook' })
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`var webhook` looks like this:

```
{
  "webhook" : function(req, res) { ... }
}
```

So your route handler setup looks like this:

```
app.get('/webhook', {
  "webhook" : function(req, res) { ... }
});
```

Which is invalid, because Express wants a function argument, not an object.

Instead, you want to use `webhook` property of the exported module object:

```
var webhook = require('./routes/webhook.js').webhook;
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, it looks like a stupid syntax error. But do you know a good way to debug node.js, like to have a breaking point and see the value of local variables?

Comment: @HaichenLiu you can try [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), which works pretty well in my experience.